# How to sort ArrayStore?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a object:

```
   store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore',{
            sortInfo: { field: "uniq_users", direction: "DESC" },
            fields: [
                {name: 'Country', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'uniq_users',      type:'int'}],
                data: [{Country: 'Ed',    users: 'Spencer'}]
    })
    store.loadData(...)
```

Why default sort don't work for field ?

Comment: Are you looking at the data in a grid? Or are you printing out the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sortInfo` property is available for ExtJS 3.x and not for the latest version. With release of version 4, the sorting is implemented through the mixin `Ext.util.Sortable`. You should be using the property `sorters` to define your sorting parameters..

Here is what you should be doing:

```
store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore',{
    sorters: [
        {property : 'uniq_users',direction: 'DESC'}
    ],
    fields: [
        {name: 'Country', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'uniq_users',      type:'int'}
    ],
    data: [{Country: 'Ed',    users: 'Spencer'}]
});
store.loadData(...);
```